# get next and previous day with PHP

Tags: php, date

I have got two arrows set up, click for next day, next two days, soon and previous day, two days ago, soon. the code seem not working? as it only get one next and previous day.

```
<a href="home.php?date=<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date))) ?>" class="prev_day" title="Previous Day" ></a> 
<a href="home.php?date=<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date))) ?>" class="next_day" title="Next Day" ></a>
```

is there a way if i click the next button, the date will continously change for the next day. for a moment it will only get one day ahead

Comment: Exactly what are you expecting?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Your code creates one link for the next day and one for previous day. What is your question?

Comment: Is the value on $date changed on each page?

Comment: sorry for unclear question! if, you click next day button, it will show the 'next day date', then if you click again, it will show the 'next two days date'...

Comment: @Gordon, `strtotime` only takes one perameter

Comment: @Alan Nope: `int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now ] )` See http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @boyee what happens when you use `$_GET['date']` instead of `$date`?

Comment: @Gordon: `$date is for todays date`. `$_GET['date']` use to get report base on the date. let say, if u click next, it will get for tmr date `2011-05-04`, if click again `2011-05-05`, again `2011-05-06` soon....

Comment: @boyee that doesnt answer my question. What happens when you use $_GET['date'] instead of $date? The second argument to strtotime is the timestamp from which relative dates will be calculated so when you pass in today's date it will of course only do tomorrow and yesterday. You have to pass in the date from the query string to have it give the date after the next day or the day before yesterday. If $date is always todays date it cannot work.

Comment: @Gordon. Apologies I have always used one parameter, `strtotime('2011-05-03 -1 day')` Everyday is a school day!

Comment: @Gordon: thanks i know what u mean :) so i just change the $date to $_GET['date'].

Comment: ...and what about a NICE&&MODERN way? : `(new DateTime('now+1day'))->format('Y-m-d')` ...that is tomorrow :) You can guess how would it look for yesterday... :)

Answer (score 253, accepted):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)))
```

Should read

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' +1 day'))
```

---

Update to answer question asked in comment about continuously changing the date.

```
<?php
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : date('Y-m-d');
$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));
?>

<a href="?date=<?=$prev_date;?>">Previous</a>
<a href="?date=<?=$next_date;?>">Next</a>
```

This will increase and decrease the date by one from the date you are on at the time.

Comment: thanks. is there a way if i click the next button, the date will continously change for the next day, if u know what i mean. for a moment it will only get 1 day ahead

Comment: $date=date('Y-m-d'); echo date($date,strtotime('-1 days')); its not give previous date. IT display only current date. How to solve this?

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date))) is fine.  That allows you to feed in the date you are calculating from, rather than the current date.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use this

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("yesterday"));
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Requirement: PHP 5 >= 5.2.0

You should make use of the **DateTime** and **DateInterval** classes in Php, and things will turn to be very easy and readable.

Example: Lets get the previous day.

```
// always make sure to have set your default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

// create DateTime instance, holding the current datetime
$datetime = new DateTime();

// create one day interval
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

// modify the DateTime instance
$datetime->sub($interval);

// display the result, or print_r($datetime); for more insight 
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');


/** 
* TIP:
* if you dont want to change the default timezone, use
* use the DateTimeZone class instead.
*
* $myTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
* $datetime->setTimezone($myTimezone); 
*
* or just include it inside the constructor 
* in this form new DateTime("now",   $myTimezone);
*/
```

*References: Modern PHP, New Features and Good Practices
By Josh Lockhart*

Comment: DateInterval is not actually intended for this purpose :) , you can just do `(new DateTime('now+1day'))->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
$time = time();
```

For previous day -

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date("n", $time),date("j",$time)- 1 ,date("Y", $time)));
```

For 2 days ago

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date("n", $time),date("j",$time) -2 ,date("Y", $time)));
```

For Next day -

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date("n", $time),date("j",$time)+ 1 ,date("Y", $time)));
```

For next 2 days

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date("n", $time),date("j",$time) +2 ,date("Y", $time)));
```

Comment: Are you sure this works in edge cases? For example if the current day is 31th. What will happen when you try to get +1?

Comment: @PavelNikolov Look at the [mktime() example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). "Wrong inputs" like "32" are allowed.

Answer (score 4):

it is enough to call it this way:

```
<a href="home.php?date=<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')) ?>" class="prev_day" title="Previous Day" ></a>
<a href="home.php?date=<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day')) ?>" class="next_day" title="Next Day" ></a>
```

Also see the [documentation](http://php.net/strtotime).

Answer (score 3):

```
strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date))
```

This returns the number of difference in seconds of the given date and the $date.so you are getting wrong result .

Suppose $date is todays date and -1 day means it returns -86400 as the difference and the when you try using date you will get 1969-12-31 Unix timestamp start date.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **'now'** as string to get today's/tomorrow's/yesterday's date:

```
$previousDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now - 1day'));
$toDay       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));
$nextDay     = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now + 1day'));
```

Comment: `'now' !== 'today'`. You could use `$previousDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - 1 day'));`

Answer (score 1):

always make sure to have set your default timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

create DateTime instance, holding the current datetime

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
```

create one day interval

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
```

modify the DateTime instance

```
$datetime->sub($interval);
```

display the result, or `print_r($datetime);` for more insight

```
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

TIP:

If you don't want to change the default timezone, use the `DateTimeZone` class instead.

```
$myTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$datetime->setTimezone($myTimezone);
```

or just include it inside the constructor in this form `new DateTime("now",   $myTimezone);`

Answer (score 0):

**Php script -1****its to Next Date**

```
<?php

$currentdate=date('Y-m-d');


$date_arr=explode('-',$currentdate);


$next_date=
Date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$date_arr[1],$date_arr[2]+1,$date_arr[0]));



echo $next_date;
?>**

**Php script -1****its to Next year**


<?php

$currentdate=date('Y-m-d');


$date_arr=explode('-',$currentdate);


$next_date=
Date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$date_arr[1],$date_arr[2],$date_arr[0]+1));



echo $next_date;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case if you want next day or previous day from today's date

> date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y")));

just change the "-1" to the "+1"
regards, Yosafat

Answer (score 0):

Very easy with the [dateTime() object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), too.

```
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
echo $tomorrow->format("Y-m-d"); // Tomorrow's date

$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
echo $yesterday->format("Y-m-d"); // Yesterday's date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Day_seconds = 86400;

$next_day = $day_timestamp + $Day_seconds;
$prev_day = $day_timestamp - $Day_seconds;
```

Comment: This unexplained snippet is not reliably true when daylight savings is a potential factor.