# Finding the next and previous date for an inputed date

Tags: php, date

I need to input a date in format, 26/12/1993 where 12 is month (december), I need to know a way to find the previous date (25/12/1993) and the next date (27/12/1993) using PHP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below example:

```
<a href="home.php?date=<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' -1 day')) ?>" class="prev_day" title="Previous Day" ></a> 
<a href="home.php?date=<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' +1 day')) ?>" class="next_day" title="Next Day" ></a>
```

It might help you.

take a look at [get next and previous day with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883571/get-next-and-previous-day-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [PHP DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object

```
$date = new DateTime('26/12/1993');
$previous_day = $date->modify('-1 day');
$next_day = $date->modify('+1 day');

print $previous_day->date_format('m/d/Y');
print $next_day->date_format('m/d/Y');
```