# Get date of -3 days in this format YYYYMMDD

Tags: php, date

I a using PHP and would like the date of third day before the script is called in the format of YYYYMMDD. How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: strtotime function in php documentation will lead you there...

Comment: Refer this link [get next and previous day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883571/get-next-and-previous-day-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new \DateTime('-3 days');
echo $date->format('Ymd');

// Alternatively, store the string in a variable
$result = $date->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$result = date('Y.m.d',strtotime("-3 days"));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this easy way

```
echo date('Ymd', strtotime("-3 days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Atleast visit [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) once before such questions

```
<?php 
    $date  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-3, date("Y"));
    echo date('Ymd', strtotime($date));
    ?>
```