# Check if today's date is passed the expiration date

Tags: php

Can someone out there help me with this:

```
<?php 
    include 'include/db_config.php';

    $result = $dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM service_info WHERE id = :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
    $result->execute();
    for ($i=0;$i = 0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++) {
        ?>

        <td><?php echo $row['datepicker']; ?></td>

        <?php



        $offset = strtotime("+1 day");
        $enddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $offset);
        echo $enddate . "</br>";
        if ($enddate < $startdate) {
            echo "expired";
        } else {
            echo "active";
        }
    }
?>
```

What I want to achieve is to find out if the date value held in `$row['datepicker']` was more than 2 days ago. If it was more than 2 days ago I want it to echo `expired` and otherwise I want it to show `active`.

For example: 
`$row['datepicker']` could contain the date: May 18, 2016 (based on the users input - not a fixed value). That would mean it's expiration date would be: May 20,2016. If today's date is greater than or equal to May 20th 2016, it should echo `expired`. If today's date was May 19th 2016 it should echo `active` because it is not yet two days in the past.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense nor is your question clear.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883571/get-next-and-previous-day-with-php

Comment: What do you want?? Explain Clearly!

Comment: where is $stardate coming from? you can compare timestamps (before passing through the date) so you can use <code>if($offset < strtotime($startdate)) { ... </code>

Comment: i want to make an expiration date. but my code doesnt seem to work . i am making a massage website where in it has a reservation and it automatically expires every 2 days @JensonMJohn

Comment: Your start date just needs to be the value of the `$row['datepicker']` right? And then you need to compare them as you are but at timestamps.

Comment: And what is the value of `$row['datepicker']` currently? What do you get if you do `echo $row['datepicker'];`?

Comment: @Henders if i do echo $row['datepicker'] the value of it is 11-May-2016 and i chooses that date and yeah its working . i just dont know how to compare it with the 2 days interval so that it will expire every 2 days

Comment: So if the current date today is 13-May-2016 you want it to say expired?

Comment: @Henders precisely . can you help me sir ? .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301753/expiration-date-in-php#comment62128404_37301753), you want to take the `$startdate` and add two days to it. If today's date is passed that time then you want to print expired and otherwise print active.

```
$startdate = "16-May-2016";
$expire = strtotime($startdate. ' + 2 days');
$today = strtotime("today midnight");

if($today >= $expire){
    echo "expired";
} else {
    echo "active";
}
```

In this case it will echo `expired` because, at the time of writing this, we are two days passed the 16th May. If you changed the `$startdate` to be 17th May it would echo `active` because that is only 1 day in the past.

For your specific problem you would want to change `$startdate` to look like this:

```
$startdate = $row['datepicker'];
```

Whenever the date specified in `$startdate` is greater than or equal to 2 days in the past it will show `expired` otherwise it will show active.

---

**What are we doing here?**

It's quite simple. We take advantage of [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the timestamp of the day it will be `+2 days` from your `$startdate` value. Then we get today's date at midnight (so the actual timestamp would be the equivalent of 18-May-2016 00:00:00).

Our last step is to compare the two timestamps and see if today's date is greater than or equal to the expiry date.

---

*Note:* This assumes that your `$startdate` is in a format that is compatible with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: so i should write my code like this?
$startdate = $row['datepicker'];
$expire = strtotime($startdate. ' + 2 days');
$today = strtotime("today midnight");

if($today >= $expire){
    echo "expired";
} else {
    echo "active";
}

Comment: Yeah, I think that should work.

Comment: it doesnt work sir . i got this error:
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (11 Maypm16 2017) at position 6 (p): The timezone could not be found in the database'

Comment: @Ginxx0009 There is an issue with the date you are trying to pass in. As your example you said the value of `$row['datepicker']` would be `11-May-2016` which works for the code I have provided. You are attempting to pass it a string like this: `11 Maypm16 2017` which is different to what you said you were passing. It looks like the value of your `$row['datepicker']` is the issue.

Comment: I used varchar not date sorry i forgot to say . Does it affect sir? @Henders

Comment: @Ginxx0009 that isn't the issue. The issue is in your code where you are attempting to create a DateTime object with the string of `11 Maypm16 2017`. If you want my solution to work you will need to remove your attempt in the final PHP tags which looks to be the cause of the issue (as it's the only place where you attempt to create a new dateTime

Comment: And now it works i just changed varchar into date but the thing is in returns 0000-00-00 expired

Comment: You are passing the value of 0000-00-00 as your `$startdate`. If you pass in the date as you said you were doing before with `11-May-2016` it will work. You're close to getting it to work you just need to make sure the value of `$row['datepicker']` is in the correct format (dd-Month-YYYY)

Comment: It is actually working because it is more than 2 days since the year 0000 which is why it says `expired`. You just need your code to pass the date you want.

Comment: on my database the format of my date is 0000-00-00 so should i follow my database date format . cause here in my datepicker its 
script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     changeMonth:true,
     changeYear:true,
     dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy"
    });
    
  });
  </script>

Comment: i was such an idiot . ofcourse i should put a data first on my database to work . i forgot i change it from varchar to date. >.< what a mess. im really sorry for making it hard for you sir >.<

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: Look at my code example. I don't have `$offset = strtotime("+1 day");` in it. That is something you've added. In my example, you can determine how many days it expires in by editing the value of: `$expire = strtotime($startdate. ' + 2 days');` and changing `+ 2 days` to be `+ 12 days` for example.

Answer (score 1):

In php 5.2+ you can use this

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
$startdate = $row['datepicker'];   
$offset = strtotime("+1 day");
$enddate = date($startdate, $offset);    
$today_date = new DateTime($today);
$expiry_date = new DateTime($enddate);

if ($expiry_date < $today_date) { // your echo stuff }
```

Comment: What is `$startdate`? It doesn't seem to have been defined.

Comment: what i mean by my code was the <?php echo $row['datepicker']; ?>
should be the starting date and may end date would be after 2 days and automatically expires . but i cant do it >.<

Comment: @Ginxx0009 Your $startdate is that only where you are picking the date from datepicker. be careful how you are storing the date in database. Otherwise this code will work without fail.

Comment: @AmitRay so how can i pass the value of my datepicker . can i do it like
this ? :
$DateToday =  Datepicker?

Comment: you can do this $start_date = $_POST["datepicker"]; as your date format will be in form 18 May 2016 . To save into database use strtotime
$timestamp = strtotime($start_date);

Comment: @AmitRay sir can you do it in a form of code . I'm really sorry but im just new to php

Comment: For a datepicker in form you can use something like this http://code.runnable.com/UdTuotHbZoQNAABq/adding-a-date-picker-to-an-input-form-field-using-jquery . To get the form data use $start_date = $_POST["datepicker"]; To save into database use $datetime = strtotime($start_date); To retrieve the date use $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$row->datetime); Then compare the two dates.

Comment: @AmitRay it says;
 Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (11 Maypm16 2017) at position 6 (p): The timezone could not be found in the database' in

Comment: Can you paste the whole code? It is difficult to know what exactly you are doing. I request you to edit the question and paste the entire code

Comment: @AmitRay i paste my whole code sir